# Fragments not visible on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

In the following code, the fragments are being dynamically inflated from a layout xml. The issue i am facing is that I dont see the fragments when i rotate the device.

If I look at the fragmentManager, I do see fragments are there. They are added and attached, but no where on the screen.

```
MenuCard extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.content);

        leftContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftContainer);
        rightContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rightContainer);


        Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.leftFragment);
        if (fragment == null) {
            LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.left_fragment, leftContainer);
        }

        fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.rightFragment);
        if (fragment == null) {
            LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.right_fragment, rightContainer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

R.layout.left_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/leftFragment"
    android:name="com.example.LeftFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/left_fragment">

</fragment>
```

R.layout.right_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rightFragment"
    android:name="com.example.LeftFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/left_fragment">

</fragment>
```

Adding the code for R.layout.content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00AFF0"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your content.xml?

Comment: It looks fine, although it's a little interesting the way your attaching the Fragments, it should work though.  I noticed you've specified LeftFragment  in both left_fragment.xml and right_fragment.xml.  Are you sure the Fragments themselves are actually showing anything on screen?  Can you do a simple test with just the fragment with a colored background on it and make sure it is showing up at all?

Comment: They show content perfectly when loaded. The issue when rotated. The mContainerId, mView, mInnerView are all null. But the fragment is visible, attached and added :o

Comment: The LeftFragment on either side is just to simplify the example

Comment: Look at the bottom post. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add following lines in your manifest inside fragment Activity's declaration:

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
```

This will prevent onCreate on screen orientation change.For handling of orientation change, you can override onConfigurationChanges.

Comment: This circumvents the issue, and I had this solution the second i saw the problem. I am more interested in figuring our what and why of what i am seeing.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of reading of the fragment manager code i came across these magical lines:

```
// For fragments that are created from a layout, when restoring from
// state we don't want to allow them to be created until they are
// being reloaded from the layout.
```

which means the correct code for my case is

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    leftContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftContainer);
    rightContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rightContainer);

    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.left_fragment, leftContainer);
    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.right_fragment, rightContainer);


    }
}
```

SupportFragmentManager will reuse the fragments in case of orientation change and only inflate the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried your design but I find it interesting. Although I don't recommend it.

The UI is not recreated because orientation is changed. This is because Activity is not recreated, hence `onCreate` is not triggered when orientation is changed. When the screen is changed due to different factors, **onCreateView** is triggered. This I never tried in the Activity subclass. It is normally done in a Fragment subclass. Actually, `onCreate` is only triggered when the App is stopped due to user action or a crash.

If/when I find a good sample of **onCreateView** method in Activity, I'll post it.